# Does vsc include some libraries without the need of writing them? (C)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I used in the past a different code editor/IDE and when I needed to use `conio.h` tools I had to write it in the header but with vscode I don't have to. Why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Comment: If you take a look at conio.h(right click the "#include <conio.h>" line and select open file), it almost exclusively forward declares the functions that will be linked to your program from the static library(which in turn either contains the implementation, or more likely, calls a dll implementing them), so the compiler can be smart enough to tell you are calling an undefined/undeclared function that has a standard function with such a name and include the header for you, as `#include` is practically "paste in place".

Comment: I doubt that you don't need to include the header files for the library functions you use. If you don't get warnings, raise the warning level, which should be at the maximum anyway. Can you provide a [mre], please?